# In $P^n$(projection of $C^{n+1}$) is a variety isomorphic to $P^1$ irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In $P^n$(projection of $C^{n+1}$) is a variety isomorphic to $P^1$ irreducible?
I think not because is the union of a line and a point at infinity

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you do not think $\mathbf P^1$ is irreducible?

Comment: yeah, I am confused

Comment: OK. Well, you correctly observe that $\mathbf P^1$ is a union of a point and an affine line, but that is _not_ enough to conclude it is reducible, because one of those two is not a _closed_ subset of $\mathbf P^1$. In fact, $\mathbf P^1$ is irreducible.

Comment: cheers now I get it

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Added aside: the property of being irreducible does not depend on the ambient space; it's an intrinsic property of the topology.